# Nvidia driver broke ubuntu kernel!

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

I am running Ubuntu 15.10, it was working fine until I decided to go to Additional Drivers and select 352 under my nvidia card. After restart, I couldn't login. The login screen was stuck in a loop (still is) and my tty went black. After doing some weird stuff I ended up getting tty back. So, now I have command line access but login is still stuck.

I `purged` nvidia*, and when I reinstalled 352.63 version it gives me the following error:

`Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.2.0-27-generic (x86_64)`

From now on, all `apt-get` give me similar error to above and I can't install anything but I can delete just fine.

Things I have tried:

- Removing `.Xauthority` file and reinstalling `lightdm`, have also `chown` it, permissions seem fine.
- Reinstalling `nvidia driver` which obviously fails as mentioned above.
- Reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop`
- Reinstalling the `kernel 4.2.0-27` gives the same error as above.

Things that are currently wrong:

- Kernel seems messed up, because all those errors relate to kernel?
- Nvidia driver and login stuck in a loop.
- Since the driver isn't working, the screen is all messed up with low resolution.

I really don't want to reinstall the OS, anyone know what I can try? Will greatly appreciate any ideas!

Log file for nvidia driver error: [make.log](https://codeshare.io/5K6mv) (idk how to share a file, sorry!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this people! If you installed or updated nvidia driver and it somehow broke your ubuntu and made it stuck in a login loop do the following:

You need terminal access, try `tty` first by `Ctrl + Alt + F1` so if you don't even have that maybe use installation disc to get access, you can easily mount your system using the installation disc and use the terminal to fix your system.

Then check `/var/log/nvidia-installer.log` and see if you had a compiler issue during the installation. It should say `ERROR` and then explain how it tried to find a `gcc` version but was unable to locate the desired one.

Problem is, you need `gcc-5.1.0` to install `nvidia-driver` but you need `gcc < 4.9` to run Nvidia's `nvcc`. Which is what I was doing, I had my gcc switched to an older version when I attempted the installation. So, just switch back to `gcc-5.1.0` using `update-alternatives` and `purge` and reinstall the nvidia driver. It should fix this issue!